# Remote webdriver can't connect to docker selenium grid

Tags: docker, selenium

I got a problem about using webdriver.remote(in docker container) to connect to the other selenium grid container. These are my docker-compose file and the python file using the webdriver.

```
python file:

sleep(10)
Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
Options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
Options.add_argument('--headless') 
driver = webdriver.Remote( 
    command_executor= 'http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
)

docker-compose file:
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.14.0
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "9090:4444"
  chromenode:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.14.0
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    links:
      - selenium-hub:hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
  flask-web:(execute python file)
   image: main
   container_name: template_flask
   depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
      - chromenode
   links:
      - selenium-hub
      - chromenode
```

The error I got :

> MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='selenium-hub', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url:

I have seen many discussions about this error but can't still solve it . Could anyone give me some tips ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a network issue between containers. I would suggest create a network for all the containers, that way they can talk to each other by using the service names defined in your docker-compose file, refer to:

```
version: "3"
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    environment:
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 16
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 180
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 60
    networks:
      - selenium_net

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3
    container_name: chrome_node
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 4
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 4
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9001:5900"
    links:
      - hub
    networks:
      - selenium_net

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug:3
    container_name: firefox_node
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 5
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 5
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9003:5900"
    links:
      - hub
    networks:
      - selenium_net

networks:
   selenium_net:
     driver: bridge
     name: selenium-net
```